# I've wrote this but i want that the image fill all the screen. What i need to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've wrote this but i want that the image fill all the screen. What i need to do?

```py
def load_image(name):
    img = pygame.image.load(name)
    return img

bg1 = load_image("Backgrounds/Back1.png")

screen.blit(bg1, (WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2))

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Do you mean as a screen background? That is heavily dependant on the operating system used.

Answer (score 0):

Create a full screen display (see [`pygame.display.set_mode()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode)):

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Use [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) to scale the scaled image to the size of the window

```py
bg1 = load_image("Backgrounds/Back1.png")
bg_scaled = pygame.transform.smoothscale(bg1, screen.get_size())
```

```py
screen.blit(bg_scaled, (0, 0))
```